# UISegmentedControl, show highlight color only when the segment is selcted

Tags: ios

I have add a UISegmentedControl to my view:

```
 UISegmentedControl *segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Red",@"Green",@"Blue"]];
 segControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);
 [segControl addTarget:self action:@selector(MySegmentControlAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
...
```

The problem I am facing is showing in the image below:
[image]

I used default color & style for it. After I selected one segment button, the button's color remains blue, even I select another segment. How to make it so that only when the segment is selcted, it shows the highlight default color, otherwise change back to the unselected style?

Here is the `MySegmentControlAction` function:

```
- (void)MySegmentControlAction:(UISegmentedControl *) segment {
    UIColor *color;
    switch(segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {

            case 0:
            color = [UIColor redColor];
            break;

            case 1:
            color = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;

            case 2:
            color = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;
    }
    self.circleColor = color;
}
```

Comment: the code looks correct. can you show what you are doing in your `MySegmentControlAction:` method?

Answer (score 0):

`segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor yourColor];`